# My TYPO3 extension's plugin is not visible in the backend

Tags: plugins, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I am new to TYPO3 , I started by creating my own extension using Extbase , the extension was successfully created and I could include it into the template of my site , now when I try to include its plugin to a page .. it's not there . I tried many times to delete the cache , and nothing changes ..

The extension's folder as well as it's mysql table were created without any problem .. but this story of the plugin made me really unconfortable.

Does any one know what could be the issue ? 
and I would also appreciate it if someone could give me a great tutorial on how to build your own TYPO3 extensions .

Thank you so much

Ps : I'm using TYPO3 6.2

Comment: Did you `Include static (from extensions)` in your root TypoScript template?

Comment: Yes I did ... List->edit template->includes -> and then select the extension from the available Items .